# Node.js async socket chat client in visual basic

Tags: vb.net, node.js, sockets, vb6

I have this code:

```
// Load the TCP Library
net = require('net');
//var sys = require('sys');

// Keep track of the chat clients
var clients = [];

// Start a TCP Server
net.createServer(function (socket) {

  // Identify this client
  socket.name = socket.remoteAddress + ":" + socket.remotePort 

  // Put this new client in the list
  clients.push(socket);

  // Send a nice welcome message and announce
  socket.write("Welcome " + socket.name + "\n");
  broadcast(socket.name + " joined the chat\n", socket);

  socket.write(tools.foo);

  // Handle incoming messages from clients.
  socket.on('data', function (data) {
    broadcast(socket.name + " >> " + data+"\n", socket);
  });

  // Remove the client from the list when it leaves
  socket.on('end', function () {
    clients.splice(clients.indexOf(socket), 1);
    broadcast(socket.name + " left the chat.\n");
  });

  // Send a message to all clients
  function broadcast(message, sender) {
    clients.forEach(function (client) {
      // Don't want to send it to sender
      if (client === sender) return;
      client.write(message);
    });
    // Log it to the server output too
    process.stdout.write(message)
  } 

}).listen(5100,"192.168.1.8");

// Put a friendly message on the terminal of the server.
console.log("Chat server running at port 5100\n");
```

working with node.js.

In practice it's a simple chat server where I've develop an iOS client with the async tcp socket and it works perfectely with a telnet client.

I would develop another client in VisualBasic but all the demos that I have tried crash at the first connection ([one of this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16916/A-Chat-Application-Using-Asynchronous-TCP-Sockets)).

how can I start the development?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is your vb code? Is it VB6 or vb.net?

In vb6 you can make the following test project:

In the components add "Microsoft Winsock Control 6.0 (SP6)

```vb
'1 form with:
'  1 winsock control: name=Winsock1
'  1 textbox control: name=txtShow  multiline=true
'  1 textbox control: name=txtCmd
'  1 command button : name=Command1
Option Explicit

Private mstrIP As String
Private mlngPort As Long

Private Sub Command1_Click()
  SendCmd txtCmd.Text
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()
  'setting initial data
  txtShow.Text = ""
  txtCmd.Text = "da"
  mstrIP = "laptop07"
  mlngPort = 7000
  DoConnect
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Resize()
  'positioning controls
  Dim sngWidth As Single, sngHeight As Single
  Dim sngCmdWidth As Single, sngCmdHeight As Single
  Dim sngShowHeight As Single
  sngWidth = ScaleWidth
  sngHeight = ScaleHeight
  sngCmdWidth = sngWidth / 2
  sngCmdHeight = 495
  sngShowHeight = sngHeight - sngCmdHeight
  txtShow.Move 0, 0, sngWidth, sngShowHeight
  txtCmd.Move 0, sngShowHeight, sngCmdWidth, sngCmdHeight
  Command1.Move sngCmdWidth, sngShowHeight, sngCmdWidth, sngCmdHeight
End Sub

Private Sub Winsock1_Connect()
  ShowTxt vbCrLf & "~ Connected" & vbCrLf
End Sub

Private Sub Winsock1_DataArrival(ByVal bytesTotal As Long)
  Dim strData As String
  Winsock1.GetData strData
  ShowTxt strData
End Sub

Private Sub Winsock1_Error(ByVal Number As Integer, Description As String, ByVal Scode As Long, ByVal Source As String, ByVal HelpFile As String, ByVal HelpContext As Long, CancelDisplay As Boolean)
  ShowTxt vbCrLf & "~ Error " & CStr(Number) & vbCrLf & Description & vbCrLf
End Sub

Private Sub ShowTxt(strTxt As String)
  'show received data
  With txtShow
    .SelStart = Len(.Text)
    .SelText = strTxt
  End With 'txtShow
End Sub

Private Sub DoConnect()
  ShowTxt "~ connecting" & vbCrLf
  With Winsock1
    If .State <> sckClosed Then .Close
    Do Until .State = sckClosed
      DoEvents
    Loop
    .Connect mstrIP, mlngPort
  End With 'Winsock1
End Sub

Private Sub SendCmd(strCmd As String)
  With Winsock1
    If .State = sckConnected Then
      .SendData strCmd
    Else
      DoConnect
    End If
  End With 'Winsock1
End Sub
```

Replace "laptop07" with the IP addres of the server.

Replace 7000 with the port number on which the server is listening.

Replace "da" with the data you want to send to the server.

Run the project and wait until you see the message that it is connected.

If you get a message that the connection timed out, then you can't reach your server from your client (wrong IP addres, wrong port number, server isn't running, firewall settings, etc.).

When you are connected, click on the command button and the text from txtCmd will be sent.
The received data will be shown in txtShow

System messages start with "~ ", received data is displayed without a header.

Comment: Perfect! It works!!! 
In the ip camp 'localhost' don't work, it want the REAL ip number of machine.
Thanks!!!!

Comment: @Kerberos you can also use: Winsock1.Connect Winsock1.LocalIP, 7000

Comment: @IlyaKurnosov thanks! i didnt know that! will try to remember to do that from now on.

Comment: Thanks! Just one thing, why I can't see the received message with a 'debug.print strdata'?

Comment: @Kerberos you should be able to see that in your debug window .. when you dont see anything then either strdata is an empty string or you are not looking at the right debug window (i prefer printing to a textbox so i can test it as an compiled exe as well)

Comment: Last question, I promise. Why returned me a 40006 error runtime if I call 'Winsock1.SendData foo' from another function? Or crash if I call the 'SendCmd' directely? Thanks!

Comment: you get that error when there is no connection. when you call senddata directly you first have to make sure that you have a connection (have look at the code of sendcmd, which is not perfect btw)

Comment: how do you call sendcmd directly? do you get any messages when it crashes?